# Why does SEEK_SET fail?

Tags: perl, yaml

When I run the below script I get

```
Can't use an undefined value as a symbol reference at ./yaml-test.pl line 52.
```

where line 52 is

```
seek $fh, 0, SEEK_SET;   # seek back to the beginning of file
```

The purpose of the script is to reproduce why I get corrupt yaml files, so the global file handles are suppose to be there.

My theory is that newly written yaml files are not overwritten, and therefore if the newly written yaml is smaller than the old, then old data will still be in the new yaml file.

**Question**

Can anyone see what is wrong with my script?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use YAML::Syck;
use Fcntl ':flock', 'SEEK_SET';
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my $acc;
my $acc_fh;

$acc->{1}{name1} = "abc";


system("rm -f test.yaml");

# write initial
open F, '>', 'test.yaml';
print F YAML::Syck::Dump($acc);
close F;


$acc->{1}{name2} = "abc";

write_yaml_with_lock($acc, $acc_fh);

$acc->{1}{name3} = "abc";

($acc, $acc_fh) = read_yaml_with_lock('test.yaml');

$acc->{1}{name4} = "abc";

write_yaml_with_lock($acc, $acc_fh);



sub read_yaml_with_lock {
    my ($file) = @_;

    open my $fh, '+<', $file or die $!;
    flock($fh, LOCK_EX) or die $!;

    my $obj = YAML::Syck::LoadFile($fh); # this dies on failure
    return ($obj, $fh);
}

sub write_yaml_with_lock {
    my ($obj, $fh) = @_;

    my $yaml = YAML::Syck::Dump($obj);
    $YAML::Syck::ImplicitUnicode = 1;
    seek $fh, 0, SEEK_SET;   # seek back to the beginning of file

    print $fh $yaml . "---\n";
    close $fh;
}
```

Comment: Using `system` to remove a file is silly. Just use `unlink 'test.yaml'`. However, it is not required to do so, since you use the `>` file open mode, which truncates your file anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You call `write_yaml_with_lock()` twice. The first time you call it `$acc_fh` is still `undef` because it is not set until two lines further down via `read_yaml_with_lock()`.